# UWP ARM System.IO Decompression performance is poor

Tags: performance, arm, zip, win-universal-app

I am noticing extremely long times to extract a zip file on ARM based devices. To extract a 20mb zip file takes over 60 seconds! I am seeing even 140 seconds on a 950XL which is supposed to be one of the more powerful ARM models.

This is the code I am using:

```
var startExtractTime = DateTime.Now;
ZipArchive za = new ZipArchive(archiveMemoryStream, ZipArchiveMode.Read);
za.ExtractToDirectory(path);
var stopExtractTime = DateTime.Now;
var durationInSeconds = stopExtractTime.Subtract(startExtractTime).TotalSeconds;
```

Is this the kind of performance I can expect from this method? Are there any other ways to get around this? I'd prefer to include a Zip file in my project instead of the HUGE directory structure that is inside this file but it I can't get good performance from ARM devices I may not have an option.

Comment: Flate compression can be very slow, but decompression should go at a reasonable speed. I wouldn't blame the ARM CPU. Have you tried doing it in native code with zlib? It may be a slow file system and not a slow CPU. Are you writing the data to internal flash or the SD card?

Comment: I am writing to the app's Temporary Data folder. I assume that is on the device so in the case of my Lumia 950 XL I would expect it to be very fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zip decompression itself should not take that much time. However, if your archive contains a lot of small files this can be a bottleneck for flash drive/internal flash memory. Try to decompress single-file 20Mb archive to check whether it is CPU or file system issue.

Comment: my archive has lots of small files.

Comment: That should be the reason of poor performance, not the compression.